# Run-time error '424' Object Required when doing userform.show on imported userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am attempting to import a userform, and show it on initial startup. The userform imports just fine, however, when attempting to show it, I keep getting a Run-time error '424' Object Required.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim wkbTarget As Excel.Workbook
Dim szTargetWorkbook As String
Dim cmpComponents As VBIDE.VBComponents
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
szTargetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set wkbTarget = Application.Workbooks(szTargetWorkbook)
Set cmpComponents = wkbTarget.VBProject.VBComponents

' IMPORT FORM
cmpComponents.Import "\\myserver.domain\Application\Forms\LOGIN.frm"

LOGIN.Show

End Sub
```

When I click End on the error, I can then show the userform just fine.

Comment: The compiler will object to you referring to an object that doesn't exist yet. You could try: `Userforms.add("LOGIN").Show`

Comment: @Rory Not exactly the compiler objecting so much as the run-time objecting to a reference to a pre-declared instance of a form that hasn't been compiled. If the `UserForms.Add` doesn't work, you might need to show it via simple sub called by `Application.OnTime`.

Comment: Userforms.add("LOGIN").Show worked PERFECTLY! Thank you so much for the immediate response!

Comment: @Rory please post this as an Answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The run-time (thanks @Comintern!) won't like you referring to an object that doesn't exist yet. You could use:

```
Userforms.add("LOGIN").Show
```

to avoid that direct reference.